# From Bitmap to File object Android

Tags: java, android, bitmap

I have bitmap object and I want to convert it into File object , for that I have this code:
(image is Bitmap object)

```
FileOutputStream out = null;
                try {
                    out = new FileOutputStream(Environment.getDataDirectory().toString()+"/"+"test.png");
                    image.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, out); 

                } catch (Exception e) {
                    Log.d ("info", “ERROR 1");
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } finally {
                    try {
                        if (out != null) {
                            out.close();
                        }
                    } catch (IOException e) {

                        Log.d ("info", “ERROR 2");
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
```

my manifest file is this :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.alessio.myapplication">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

but I get this error:

```
10:57:27.573 29888-29888/com.example.alessio.myapplication W/System.err: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /data/test.png: open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)
08-20 10:57:27.573 29888-29888/com.example.alessio.myapplication W/System.err:     at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:452)
08-20 10:57:27.573 29888-29888/com.example.alessio.myapplication W/System.err:     at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:87)
08-20 10:57:27.573 29888-29888/com.example.alessio.myapplication W/System.err:     at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:127)
08-20 10:57:27.573 29888-29888/com.example.alessio.myapplication W/System.err:     at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:116)
```

I want to save file object in internal storage and I don’t understand because I get this error.

Can you help me?

Answer (score 0):

Do not use `Environment.getDataDirectory()`.

If by "internal storage", you mean [what the Android SDK refers to as internal storage](https://commonsware.com/blog/2014/04/07/storage-situation-internal-storage.html), use `getFilesDir()`, called on a `Context`, such as your `Activity`.

If by "internal storage", you mean what the user calls "internal storage" but [the Android SDK refers to as external storage](https://commonsware.com/blog/2014/04/08/storage-situation-external-storage.html), use `getExternalFilesDir()` (also on `Context`) or `Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory()`.

Answer (score 0):

In addition what CommonsWare said, don't use +"/"+ as path separator. use `Environment.getPathSeparator()` 
Also take care you have a file writer that can create a file if not existent.